# Sample Space for this problem

Tags: probability

When house prices go up, the house loss rate is $.09$, and the house loss rate when prices going down is $.28$. The chance that the prices rise is $0.05$. What is the chance that the house lost?

$\text{Solution Final}$

Let event $B=\{\text{house price goes up}\}$ and let $C=\{\text{House price goes down}\}$
Then $P(F)=P(F|B)P(B)+P(F|B_2)P(C)= P(B)+P(C)=.28(.05)+.09(.95)=.0995$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last line is correct, although it might have been easier to have your sample space be $$C_1=\text{prices go up}$$ and $$C_2=\text{prices go down}$$ so that $\omega = C_1 \cup C_2$.

Then you would have the same calculation without the two zero terms.

Answer (score 2):

> Problem: Suppose that the probability that the individual loses his house when prices going up is .09, and that the individual chances of losing his house when prices going down is .28. If the chance that the prices rise is 0.05 then what is the chance that the house goes into foreclosure.

Your solution is correct, just a little awkward.   I suggest defining events *before* identifying the sample space.   It will save a lot of typing, and give you more meaningful labels than $B_4$, *et cetera*.

My Solution:

Let $F$ be the event of a foreclosure, and $R$ be the event of a price rise.

So we're given: $\Pr(F\mid R)=0.09, \Pr(F\mid \neg R)=0.28), \Pr(R)=0.05$

Then the sample space is: $\omega = \{F\cap R, F\cap \neg R, \neg F\cap R, \neg(F\cup R)\}$.
$$\begin{align}\therefore
\Pr(F) & = \Pr(F\cap R)+\Pr(F\cap \neg R) & \text{by mutual independence}
\\ & = \Pr(F\mid R)\Pr(R)+\Pr(F \mid \neg R)\Pr(\neg R)& \text{by conditional probability}
\\ & = (0.{\bf 0}9)(0.05)+(0.28)(1-0.05) & \text{on substituting known values}
\\ & = 0.2705 & \text{on evaluation}
\end{align}$$

Comment: I think you got your last part a bit flip flopped.

Comment: I corrected a typo and recalculated, but the figures match up. @user60887